# Find NULLs and replace by number in Derived Column Transformation

Tags: loops, ssis, etl

Using MS SSIS, I created a Derived Column Transformation that check all columns to see if the value is null and if it is then it replaces it by a zero, otherwise it leaves the number in the field like so:

```
 ISNULL(Age) ? 0 : Age
```

It is okay with tables with not many columns to check but for tables with many columns, I wondering if it is possible to loop through the columns rather than having to put a conditional check (as above) for each column in the Derived Column Transformation module.

Comment: you can mention multiple column name you want to replace rite? in _DERIVED COLUMN NAME_

Comment: Sorry Vijaykumar, I don't understand. If I add multuple columns in the 'Derived Column Name' what would I get with that. Under 'Derived Column' I'm selecting the column what will replace the value. Therefore even if I add multuple columns in 'Derived Column Name', the result of the contidion will apper in one column. I need to check all the columns and then correct each of the columns if required. Maybe I'm missing something. :-(

Comment: Maybe with a script and a dump of the column names. But that might be more trouble than it's worth. I usually just bite the bullet and go through every column individually.